# Jquery Not Running on radio Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show alert box when user select radio button  i have written the jquery to do this .
here is my code

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {

    alert("clicked");

   });

  $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

});
</script>
</head>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme1"/>Theme1</li>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme2"/>Theme2</li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox"  name="view1" />Tags</li>                        
</ul>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme3"/>Theme3</li>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme4"/>Theme4</li>
</ul>
```

I have written this code this code seems perfect for me but still jquery is not running
Please help

Comment: You don't seem to have an element with the id `checkbox_div`?

Comment: BUT still its not working after adding id checkbox_div

Comment: See my answer @RockingBirds

Answer (score 0):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/04nh2f71/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").click(function() { // removed #checkbox_div 

    alert("clicked");

   });

  $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

});
</script>
</head>
<ul>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme1"/>Theme1</li>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme2"/>Theme2</li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox"  name="view1" />Tags</li>                        
</ul>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme3"/>Theme3</li>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme4"/>Theme4</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkbox_div input:radio").click(function() {

    alert("clicked");

   });

  $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");

});
</script>
</head>
<ul id="checkbox_div"><!-- add id="checkbox_div" -->
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme1"/>Theme1</li>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme2"/>Theme2</li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox"  name="view1" />Tags</li>                        
</ul>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme3"/>Theme3</li>
<li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme4"/>Theme4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `#checkbox_div` from your jQuery selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").click(function() { //No #checkbox_div
    alert("clicked");
   });
  $("input:radio:first").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
});
```

This is because no element exists that has the id `checkbox_div`, and so you are trying to run your jQuery on click of a nonexistent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/o7Lxc2ep/

---

Or, if you must keep the specificity, add that id (checkbox_div) to your `ul`

```
<ul id="checkbox_div"> <!-- Here, add that id -->
    <li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme1"/>Theme1</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme2"/>Theme2</li>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox"  name="view1" />Tags</li>                        
        </ul>
    <li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme3"/>Theme3</li>
    <li><input type="radio"  name="theme" value="theme4"/>Theme4</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/b0vszhuz/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have a value for "#checkbox_div", try adding an id to your radio buttons.

```
<li><input type="radio"  id="checkbox_div" name="theme" value="theme1"/>Theme1</li>
```